# C#, Calculating Download Speed, Where's The Problem?

Tags: c#, networking, download

I want to calculate download speed as kbps (kb per second). There's a problem in the code, it doesn't show actual speed. And I'm really tired of this work. Also, when using `(TotalDownloadSize / ElapsedTime)` formula it shows more realistic results but you know it will get average value and it will be stupidity.

It usually gives 4000 and it's basicly because of chunk 4096 when I set it to 128 that time I get 50/100/125 values.

```
DateTime dlElapsed;
private delegate void UpdateProgessCallback(Int64 BytesRead, Int64 TotalBytes, Int32 CurrentBytes);
private void UpdateProgress(Int64 BytesRead, Int64 TotalBytes, Int32 CurrentBytes)
{
    DateTime Elapsed = DateTime.Now;
    var progress = Convert.ToInt32((BytesRead * 100) / TotalBytes);
    var elaps = (Elapsed - dlElapsed).TotalSeconds;
    long kbps;

    if (elaps > 0)
    {
        kbps = Convert.ToInt64((CurrentBytes / elaps) / 1024);
        updateLabelText(String.Format("Downloading ({0} kbps)...", kbps));
    }
    // Make progress on the progress bar
    if (progress < progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progress;

    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
    }
    dlElapsed = DateTime.Now;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Some stuff here...
    int byteSize = 0;
    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];

    FileStream strLocal= new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    dlElapsed = DateTime.Now;
    while ((byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
        this.Invoke(new UpdateProgessCallback(this.UpdateProgress), 
            new object[] { strLocal.Length, totalbyte, byteSize});
    }
    updateLabelText("Download complete!");
    strLocal.Close();
    }

}
```

So where's the problem?

Comment: obligatory comic: http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: And a note: The backgrounworker already has a ProgressChanged event, no reason to make your own callback. And if you do, look at BeginInvoke().

Comment: Most "current speed" measurements I've seen appear to show "average speed so far" (total downloaded size so far divided by total elapsed time so far).

Comment: I want to do it in Real-Time.

Comment: Well, Real-time == Inaccurate

Comment: @PythEch - I suggest displaying how many bytes you have left to download instead of the speed.  You can only display the average download speed, there really isn't a good way to display your current download speed, because it can change at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So where's the problem?

You're coarsely sampling something that varies a lot.

Consider buffering measurements and averaging the last 5 or so. Look for implementations of a "running average".

Comment: But it's not the programmatic way.

Comment: And, it doesn't work (reseting dlElapsed at 5/10/15th result) gives ultra-unlogical speed results. :/

Comment: I didn't mention or mean resetting dlElapsed.

Comment: @PythEch - What do you mean the "programmatic way".  Taking the last 5 calculations and comming up with an average would be a valid way to display what you want.

Comment: @PythEch - As Daniel B pointed out. There are some basic problems with your current code you should address.

Comment: Ok then, accepting this answer but it seems I have a lot work to do.

Comment: Ok done with it it works now. Thanks all. It gives similar results as I see in the Firewall's counter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my first comment would be that your code is not thread safe, so when you set `dlElapsed = DateTime.Now;`, it's not the same `dlElapsed` value that `UpdateProgress` is going to be checking.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - care to explain the "safe enough" comment?  There's a class variable being accessed from two separate threads, without much attempt at synchronisation.

Comment: it's (dlElapsed) been accessed from only UpdateProgress and gives better but still stupid results. It usually gives 1600.

Comment: The value is set (once) well before it's first use. After that, only the progress code uses it. But you're right, the proper thing would be to set it just before calling RunWorkserAsync()

Comment: @PythEch - If it gives "stupid" results then its likely your approach.

Comment: @ramhound: No, look at the code. Any threading issues would only affect the first value shown. After that dlElpsed is only used by 1 thread.

Comment: OK guys, let's not get into a flame-war; I see what Henk's saying as well (if there is any threading issue, it's unlikely to be noticed).  The part about "Well, my first comment would be" was a hint that there are several other, off-topic things wrong with this code.

Comment: Tried using SingleThreading method now it shows faster (I mean bigger kbps) results than my bandwith capibility. But the results are changing slower.

Comment: @PythEch - as Henk points out, without keeping a running total, the best you can hope for is a series of rapidly changing values.  You should definitely try to average out the last 10 seconds' downloads, or something like that.